# How to add View-port colour and View-port specular to object in cycle render.?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

First of all, sorry for my English. I am new to blender animation. I have a problem regarding material colours, my problem is I can`t get colour same like texture shading. any one can help me on this point. I am working in cycle render.

**1) Texture Shading Viewport.**

[image]

**2) Render Viewport(cycle render).**

[image]

**How can set colour in render same as texture shading Viewport.?**

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15459/599

Comment: This is not working i have checked. @gandalf3

Comment: is there any tutorial for this.? @gandalf3

Answer (score 1):

what you have is this:

[image: current]

what you want is something like this:

[image: target]

what you miss is two things:

There is no light source in the scene. You can have lamps like in the following screenshot, ore use an image in the world background (yours is monochrome), or combine both.

[image: light]

the material setup only has a diffuse shader to it. This shader will only return diffuse color information, so specular lights won't show up anyways, no matter what you try. Mix the shader with for example a Glossy shader, which catches some reflection:

[image: material]

from here you can take it to however sophisticated you want. Add fresnel, maps, vertex colors, whatnot, but without proper material setup and proper lighting, no scene can look cool  :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe dirty vextex textures could help you. AndrewPrice made a good tutorial about it here: https://youtu.be/nX4dkwU1pyQ

You could also try to work with fresnel / layer weight: [What does the Cycles Fresnel Node do?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-does-the-cycles-fresnel-node-do)

Note that you are not in textured mode in your screenshot. You are in solid mode. The way how that behaves can be changed in Preferences > System > Solid mode OpenGL lights. (See here: https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/system.html)

Comment: Yes, I forget to change object mode to texture mode but it look same like object mode. I trying your answer... thanx for help..

Comment: I hope the dirty textures help. Btw. how have you lit the scene? A rim light could do wonders to the thing.

Comment: If you look up rim light, you can well see what I mean: https://www.google.fi/search?q=rim+light&prmd=ivmn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAk7fcjZfKAhXj6HIKHb97AqMQ_AUIBygB

Answer (score 0):

The color you have selected in the Material > Settings > Viewport Color and Specular Color only affects the viewport. The reason being the viewport uses GLSL OPENGL shading model to display in realtime your mesh in the blend file. It has nothing to do with the output of colors in your final render.

In fact you can change the viewport material color to blue, and cycle will only take the color that is on the diffuse node. It's the diffuse node that cycle cares about. So you will never get identical representation of the final out put of the file until you select render preview in the viewport.

The use for viewport material color , is so that artist would not have a 100 object with the same color. You can imagine it would be difficult to differentiate high number of objects on screen with the same color.