# What is this Fresnel node?

Tags: materials, node-editor, procedural

I was trying to reproduce defmaka's Node setup from [this BA article](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?380301-Struggling-with-concrete) seen [here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=398070&d=1441259961), and came across this **Fresnel** Node:

[image]

It looks like a **Geometry Node**, but is called a **Fresnel Node**.

Alternatively, I couldn't make the **Edge Detection** part of the setup or the material look anywhere near their result.

I've tried moving around several sets of values, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

**What is wrong with my setup?**

[image]

Comment: It is Geometry Node with label changed to Fresnel name.

Comment: That's what I used but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-does-the-cycles-fresnel-node-do and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51143/how-does-the-mix-shader-work-when-using-a-fresnel-node-as-a-factor

Answer (score 3):

Real objects both reflect and adsorb light. How much reflection you see at each point of the object depends on the angle at which you look at it.  Think of a lake of clear water.  Up close, none of the water is reflected, so you see to the bottom. Farther away, the water reflects more, so you see less into the water and more of what is reflected by the water.

The fresnel node applies this effect.  There are several good tutorials on Physics Based Rendering (PBR) that talk about Fresnel effect and using the Fresnel node.  I recommend a two part tutorial by Blender Guru. [Part 1](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/pbr-shader-tutorial-pt1) contains a pointer to part 2.

Comment: Just to clarify, the fresnel node is completely different than the one on the image, which is indeed a geometry node that has been re-named as "fresnel" https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdZJN.png